# Is there a faster way to encode png then PngBitmapEncoder on c#

Tags: c#, performance, encoding, png, emgucv

I'm encoding `ushort[]` to Gray16 png, each value in ushort represent one pixel and I'm using 14 bits from the 16 on ushort.

I search a faster way to encode my array into png:

```
ushort[] bytes = getBytes();

bitmap.WritePixels(
    new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height),
    bytes,
    width * MainWindow.BYTES_PER_BGR16_PIXEL, 0);

BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
var stream = new MemoryStream();
encoder.Save(stream);
```

Is there a faster way to do this encode (maybe using emgucv library)?